# JQuery Doesn't seem to work for server control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I tried to call jQuery function from my aspx page but it doesn't fire although it was working fine before but I think something happened that causes like this issue.

I have a div works as a button:

```
<div id="BtnContainer" runat="server" class="BtnContainer">add container</div>
```

and I need when click on it to show another popup  div

I am using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#BtnContainer").click(function () {
            alert("working");
            $("#ContainerPanel").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have included the jquery library via internet and local files but no one works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%# ResolveUrl("assets/js/jquery.js") %>"></script>
```

and tried

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Be informed that I tried the above in simple html file and it works fine and the alert was fired.

Is there any solution ?

Comment: Do you have the div in a placeholder?

Comment: no i tried to put it in placeholder but it didn't work so i removed the placeholder. but it was working fine without placeholder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspect your HTML when the page renders. Since you're using `runat="server"` on the element the ID is being altered on you.

Instead try using the class name to identify the element you want to attached the click event to.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".BtnContainer").click(function () {
        alert("working");
        $("#ContainerPanel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

You could use the `<%=BtnContainer.ClientID=>` property to get the real ID as others have suggested but then you need to have your javascript inside your .aspx page instead of nice and tidy in a (minified) .js file.

Mixing the C# aspect with the JS gets a bit ugly (IMO).

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `runat='server'`, ASP.NET will generate different ID for your `div`. Check it in HTML. You will have to use `<%=BtnContainer.ClientID=>` to generate correct ID in your script (inside of your .aspx):

```
$("<%=BtnContainer.ClientID=>").click(function () {
     alert("working");
     // more code here
});
```

or maybe select it through a class DOM property like so:

```
$(".BtnContainer").click(function () {
     alert("working");
     // more code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put an element in a PlaceHolder it prepends `PlaceHolderName_` to your ID

Try Using

```
$("#MainPlaceHolder_BtnContainer")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your document.ready your id should be <%=btndiv.ClientId%>. Sorry for the bad formatting, doing this from stackexchange app